# Typescript 5.0.2 emitDecoratorMetadata does not work without experimentalDecorators

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to use the new decorator feature with TypeScript 5 and I need to use the decorator metadata used to get the runtime types.

I already set the emitDecoratorMetadata in tsconfig but it doesn't work without experimentalDecorators. I would expect to be able to use emitDecoratorMetadata without experimentalDecorators and get the runtime type in the new decorator syntax.

Any idea why this doesn't work?
Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=false&moduleResolution=99&target=1&jsx=0&module=100&pretty=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIigUwGYBtkGMYFoTIwCGAJkcQgNwBQ1qArgHY7ASNwCSjAVtjABTEoAc0IAuOEUYBPADRwsbGMgAeMCQBFs0ctADCS1TACUcAN604cFDHpR2DZjFbtBAC2ABnCVOmmLVlaKjJ7wqMDI6CQAKtJgyAYhMFD0ONBwALxwAEpomDgAdKIwAPIA7owAsoSk5ET8CCTInsDCjGIwccgI8jAenvLBymoFjEQEkp5woVDAjMLGNIEKbJ4QmAXoEML8AAYAJGbhkTFdiTOpMNAAvnAARvTwqvE4yCRwV-fIiADaWOhETxTQ5cXg4Ih3TCxeLXAC6CGmcyw3wA5H0vCi4F5JHBDujPAVghc0lBRuNkLc5qEpMiCrtFrRqMsbHZ2Ix6Oh0JNJDI4AB6PlwRjIMpwY5RaEJVbJS7QfgMqzXahK6j-QFTUF8CFQrrmSxwMD0SHALDWZCkNjoaQfZowACEEnZIDuyCgNBVaqBcGitr0AK9FiZcAAApqcEHDcbTSgLYwrWKIlEHZweFrIchJcrGUT4MpQpkhSLvb7-Z55TQietkJttns8baCuKSNd5A8nioXsp3p8XZJ0x8IHBijysUkad8IKhcWYw8R05LbmVgH0Pm5vsLRU1FFBdFAxUwWGwiOhl9J6UA) example.

Comment: Malformed playground link

Comment: TypeScript 5.0 added support for ECMAScript decorators. It supports what could be called TypeScript decorators since long time ago (7 years or so). The two types of decorators are not compatible. The compiler option `--experimentalDecorators` triggers the usage of the old style decorators and they usually need `--emitDecoratorMetadata` to work properly. First you have to decide which type of decorators you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Typescript 5.0 #Decorators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#differences-with-experimental-legacy-decorators) the `--emitDecoratorMetadata` won't be supported:

> This new decorators proposal is not compatible with
> --emitDecoratorMetadata,  and it does not allow decorating parameters.  Future ECMAScript proposals may be able to help bridge that gap.